# Presto - select all columns from unnested column along with regular column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have an athena table(created from json data dump) which has a nested array in one column. I am able to unnest them using the below query.

```
select root.Profile,
addressdata.town, addressdata.territory, addressdata.postalCode, addressdata.country, 
street.addressLine1, street.addressLine2, street.door, streetID, addressID
From 
sampletable a 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(root.address.primaryAddresses) WITH ORDINALITY as t(addressdata, addressID)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(addressdata.streetAddress) WITH ORDINALITY as t(street, streetID)
```

The problem is, instead of using `addressdata.town`, `addressdata.territory`, i would like to select all the columns without mentioning the column names along with the regular nonnested columns.

I tried  `select root.profile, addressdata.*` but this is returning everything in a single column.

Please help!

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand, you are getting the right result, but you want to join other columns from `addressdata` as well. 
If that's the case, you could something like:

```
WITH base_table AS (
    SELECT
        root.Profile,
        addressdata.town AS town,
        addressdata.territory,
        addressdata.postalCode,
        addressdata.country,
        street.addressLine1,
        street.addressLine2,
        street.door,
        streetID,
        addressID
    FROM sampletable a
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(root.address.primaryAddresses)
        WITH ORDINALITY AS t(addressdata, addressID)
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(addressdata.streetAddress)
        WITH ORDINALITY AS t(street, streetID)
),
SELECT
    base_table.*,
    addressdata.*
FROM base_table
JOIN addressdata
    ON base_table.town = addressdata.town
```

It's a bit more work to join the tables, but makes the code more readable for future.